# Eclipse BIRT autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, birt

I am using Eclipse 3.4.2+ Birt 2.3.2.

**Code:**

```
var sqlText = new String();
sqlText.
```

When i press dot button I have not auto-complete. What can I do for fix this?